# Display receiver messages in this.state.message

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, state

I am using react-native-gifted-chat(https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat) to create a chat interface on my app, I want to load messages from my database, But how can I specify it in react-native-gifted-chat that the receiver sent a message not the sender, i.e Before the app loads, the messages are loaded into `this.state.messages`, according to the documentation, this is how it should be

```
 {
 _id: 1,
 text: 'My message',
 createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 5, 11, 17, 20, 0)),
 user: {
 _id: 2,
 name: 'React Native',
 avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
 },
 image: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
 // Any additional custom parameters are passed through
 }
```

The documentation only states how to specify the sender's message but not the receiver, please how can the receiver's message be shown, i.e

```
  {
  _id: 2,
  text: 'Receiver's message',
  createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 6, 11, 17, 20, 0)),
  user: {
   _id: 2,
  name: 'Receiver',
  avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_o3.png',
  },
  image: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_o3.png',
  }
```

Comment: The key "_id" in the "user" key of the message object should differ from one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example in https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/blob/master/example/App.js you can see an onReceive() function there.

```
 onReceive(text) {
    this.setState((previousState) => {
      return {
        messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, {
          _id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000),
          text: text,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            // avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        }),
      };
    });
  }
```

You can fire this function like this when receive message.(when state change)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the active user by adding a property to the GiftedChat component:

```
<GiftedChat
        messages={this.state.messages}
        onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
        user={{
          _id: 1,
        }}
      />
```